# Yeoman Webapp Generator LiveReload Snippet Not Working

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs, yeoman, livereload

I have been trying to adopt the GruntFile.js in the WebApp Generator and mould it to my needs. The issue I am having with the generator is that it does not inject the LiveReload middleware snippet. So for example the following piece of code under the connect section of the GruntFile is as follows:

```
       livereload: {
            options: {
                middleware: function (connect) {
                    return [
                        mountFolder(connect, '.tmp'),
                        mountFolder(connect, yeomanConfig.app),
                        lrSnippet
                    ];
                }
            }
        }
```

This surely cannot be right since the lrSnippet needs to be called before mountFolder()? Right? So if I do the following:

```
       livereload: {
            options: {
                middleware: function (connect) {
                    return [
                        lrSnippet,
                        mountFolder(connect, '.tmp'),
                        mountFolder(connect, yeomanConfig.app)
                    ];
                }
            }
        }
```

It works on subsequent requests. So it will work on one request, then when I refresh, I it hangs. Refresh again it works. Very strange. I played around with the connect-livereload plugin and every subsequent request is a Cannot GET /. Does someone have a working livereload and grunt-watch GruntFile? I know the latest version of grunt-watch has liveReload baked in.

Comment: I had a similar problem with livereload not working out of the box. I swapped the lrsnippet round as you suggested and it worked. I don't get the alternate request errors you are getting. Maybe you should try updating everything and retrying.

Comment: Awesome - thanks. Just borrowed the GruntFile from the Backbone generator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a known [bug](https://github.com/yeoman/generator-webapp/issues/63) and we're currently looking into it.

Comment: Thanks Sindre. Is it an actual issue with The Gruntfile, connect-livereload, or grunt-contrib-connect? Was trying to hunt it down. The Backbone GruntFile and Yeoman generator seem to work fine.